# How can I override a Ruby on Rails module method via metaprogramming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

As much I would like to I still don't know how to implement metaprogramming.

For views rendered from my Admin::Base controller I would like override the Rails `compute_public_path` located under ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper, so that all my admin's layout files will be under public/admin.

There is probably a better way to this, but at this point I want to learn how to do it this way.

I put this in Admin::Base controller:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  def compute_public_path(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
    super(source, "admin/#{dir}", ext = nil, include_host = true)
  end
end
```

but it gives me:

```
super: no superclass method `compute_public_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1032240a8>
```

Which doesn't surprise me.

---

If I try this in my admin helper:

```
def compute_public_path_with_admin(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
  compute_public_path_without_admin(source, "admin/#{dir}", ext, include_host)
end

alias_method_chain :compute_public_path, :admin
```

I get "undefined method 'compute_public_path' for module 'AdminHelper'", which I am guessing happens because `compute_public_path` is a private method.

I found this works:

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.class_eval do
  def compute_public_path_with_admin(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
    compute_public_path_without_admin(source, "admin/#{dir}", ext, include_host)
  end

  alias_method_chain :compute_public_path, :admin
end
```

as long as I set `config.cache_classes` to `false`, otherwise I get a stack level too deep error.

Thanks to [Squeegy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/squeegy) for pointing me in the right direction.

How can I make this work with disabling class caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compute_public_path_with_admin(source, dir, ext = nil, include_host = true)
  compute_public_path_without_admin(source, "admin/#{dir}", ext, include_host)
end

alias_method_chain :compute_public_path, :admin
```

`compute_public_path` will now call your implementation, which then calls the original implementation.

See: [Is alias_method_chain synonymous with alias_method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034586/is-alias-method-chain-synonymous-with-alias-method)

Comment: But where do I place this code?  Does it go in the controller, or into an initializer?

Comment: Place it the class or module that has the method you want to override.    Like perhaps a helper that all your admin views share in common?  Not actually where this method would get called from so you may have to play around a little.

Comment: What if the method is private? I can't seem to override it.

Comment: Thanks for your input Squeegy, I still need to figure out how to make it work with class caching on, but I am so close now thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't do this.**

The accepted answer will get what you wanted, but what you want might have dangerous security implications.

Why would you want your admin layouts under `public`? There's a reason why Rails by default puts them under `app/views/layouts`: No one will be able to read their source there.

If you put them in `public`, they are basically readable for any visitor.

If you put them where they belong, you're not exposing your layout code. And on top of that, **you can structure `app/views/layouts` any way you want without any metaprogramming**, i.e. without having to hack framework internals.