# Ruby on rails: fields_for do nothing if defined submodel_attributes=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have such code in new.erb.html:

```
<% form_for(@ratification) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <% f.fields_for :user do |fhr| %>
    <p>
      <%= fhr.label :url %><br />
      <%= fhr.text_field_with_auto_complete :url %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If i have empty Ratification.rb it is ok, fields_for works ok.

But if I wrote:

```
class Ratification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

or

```
class Ratification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  def user_attributes=(attr)
  ...
  end
end
```

f.fields_for yields nothing! Why!?

Rails: 2.3.8

Plugin for autocomplete: [repeated_auto_complete](http://github.com/patshaughnessy/auto_complete)

Answer (score 4):

just add an **=** (**EQUAL**) after <% in the f.fields_for

like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :user do |fhr| %>
    <p>
        <%= fhr.label :url %><br />
        <%= fhr.text_field_with_auto_complete :url %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

obs: you have to do the same in Rails 3

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to build a user in your controller, like

```
# controller
def new
   @ratification = Ratification.new
   @ratification.build_user
end
```

What about

```
<% f.fields_for :user, @ratification.user do |fhr| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```

?

I believe if you use

```
<% f.fields_for :user do |fhr| %>
```

you should have `@user` as instance variable. But in your case you have `@ratification.user`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redefine `user_attributes` since you will overwrite the standar behaviour that ActiveRecord specifies for it. If still knowing this you need to redefine `user_attributes` try using [alias_method_chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034586/is-alias-method-chain-synonymous-with-alias-method).

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you doing this wrong? If Ratification belongs to a user, then the user model should accept nested attributes for ratifications, not the other way around.

So if users have many ratifications, and if you want to submit multiple ratifications for a user in a single form, then you would use accept nested attributes for ratification in the user model.

And you would do somewhere in the users controller

```
@user = User.new
2.times { @user.ratifications.build } # if you want to insert 2 at a time
```

I tried to do something similar in the console:

```
@user = User.new
@user.ratifications.build # this works
```

But if I did

```
@ratification = Ratification.new
@ratification.user.build # this fails
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem and was able to fix it.  The problem was that `fields_for` takes `:user` as an argument while the argument should be `@ratification.user`

Hence, replace

```
<% f.fields_for :user do |fhr| %>
```

with

```
<% f.fields_for @ratification.user do |fhr| %>
```

That's it.